# dropdownlist usercontrol

Tags: drop-down-menu, user-controls

How to change dropdownlist seleted index in C#. I am binding dropdownlist in usercontrol.

seleted value should change form page to page .

I am doing this but return -1

in aspx page i am find contorl tryint to change seleted index

DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)ucSearchControl1.FindControl("ddlSearchType");

ddl.SelectedIndex = 2;

Answer (score 2):

you can use selectedindex_changed event for dropdownlist.
so wherever you select item it will fire this event and it will give you selected item's index.